# ISNULL is not helping the data to show with empty strings in this query

Tags: sql, sql-server

In this query, using `isnull` or `COALESCE` OR `CAST` is not helping me to replace null values to empty string or blank

```
(
```

Comment: Edit your question and provide sample data and desired results.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Presumably, your problem is that the subquery is returning no results.  The recommended solution uses `ISNULL()`, but *outside* the subquery:

```
isnull( (select doc.ProviderdocNumber
         from livefdb.dbo.Misprovider_Infoprovider doc
         where doc.SourceID = RA_M.SourceID and 
               doc.UnvUserID = AA_EPS.EpisodeProceduredoctor_UnvUserID
        ), '') as doctor_primary,
```

You could use `COALESCE()` or `ISNULL()` inside the subquery, if you use aggregation so it always returns exactly one row:

```
(select coalasce(max(doc.ProviderdocNumber), '')
 from livefdb.dbo.Misprovider_Infoprovider doc
 where doc.SourceID = RA_M.SourceID and 
       doc.UnvUserID = AA_EPS.EpisodeProceduredoctor_UnvUserID
) as doctor_primary,
```

Answer (score 1):

Your query suggests me to use `apply` :

```
SELECT . . . , COALESCE(tt.ProviderdocNumber, ',') AS doctor_primary
FROM . . .  OUTER APPLY
    ( SELECT TOP (1) doc.ProviderdocNumber -- You can also use `MAX()` instead
      FROM livefdb.dbo.Misprovider_Infoprovider doc
      WHERE doc.SourceID = RA_M.SourceID and 
            doc.UnvUserID = AA_EPS.EpisodeProceduredoctor_UnvUserID
      ORDER BY ??? -- if use `MAX()`, then no need to use `ORDER BY`
    ) tt;
```

`???` specify `pk` column that specify your column ordering.